# How to load a separate view in to an XAML at runtime in Windows Phone 8.1.....?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a Windows Phone 8.1 Application, which has two tabs on the top of screen. Depending on user selection, the area below the tabs is updated. Now I have implemented this by defining two stack panels( one for each tab view ), and changing its visibility when user clicks a tab( Collapse one view and Make other visible). I also have separate event handlers in each of the view(like button clicks) This approach is  working fine. What I need is to split the two view into two separate classes or even pages..or something(I exactly dont know how to do..), which can be loaded below my tabs at runtime depending on user selection of the tab.I need the event handlers to be defined in the separate portion..ie classes or even pages..or something...like that (not in the same .cs file of the MainPage)

```
I need  something like  fragments in Android.

What is the best approach to achieve this in Windows Phone 8.1 ..?
```

Comment: Use "User Controls", they will help you have different classes for different views and you can load them dynamically onto your page, but I would suggest you load them from Xaml and at runtime just change their visibility. See if this helps.

Comment: Can I know why you suggest changing visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `UserControl`. It allows you to do everything you have described. Right-click on your project name in *SolutionExplorer*, then choose *Add* > *New Item...* > *User Control*.

It's just like *Page* with CS file, where you can have event handlers.

Then just replace your stack panels with these newly created *user controls* in your main layout.

Changing visibility is fine. If control is *collapsed* at start, then it won't be loaded until its visibility is set to visible (I use this *visibility trick* in my apps to show to the user page loading... but it's a topic for another conversation).

Comment: As I understand from the User Control, its just a new control and doesnot have any life cycle associated with it. So the life cycle has to be taken care from the MainPage. Is that correct.... or does UserControl have its own OnNavigatedTo and related methods

Comment: No UserControl will not have navigation events.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Visibility` Property, Use the `Opacity` property to hide or show a control, which improves the app performance. And when you change the Visibility, the entire control is redrawn so takes a bit more time when you are having complex xaml in your UserControl.

And if you want to make use of the Navigation parameters, You can use two `Frames` in a `Grid`, and you can navigate to each page through each `Frame`. This is possible only in windows phone 8.1 app.

Sample Code:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame Name="frame1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Frame Name="frame2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        frame1.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        frame2.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));
        }
```